# Terminal Display Incorrect

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm running kubuntu right now. Output from `echo $TERM` is `xterm-256color`, `echo $SHELL` is `/bin/bash`.

It seems the terminal isn't displaying correctly, depending on what command I do, even though it registers properly in terms of what is evaluated.

- Pressing the backspace key will correctly delete the character, but instead print an additional space
- Pressing up or down will append the previous/next command in history to the end of the line (visually)
- Same with reverse-i-search

[image: sample image]

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: When did this problem start? Have you rebooted? Did you modify `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`? Do you have any other terminal to test? (`qterminal` shouldn't pull in many dependencies.) What happens if you use the corresponding files from `/etc/skel`?

Comment: It looks like this problem started after I tried to install spark and pyspark, if I'm remembering correctly. The only lines I've added to my `.bashrc` that are unexpected are related to that. I've rebooted a couple times since then, and the problem persists, even in qterminal.